# Unable to fetch JSON data on WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on WordPress website and i have JSON file containing pick-up points data in Russia, placed in WordPress directory "wp-content/uploads/file.json"
and I am trying to fetch cities name from JSON and populate on dropdown using this code:

```
$json_data = wp_remote_get('http://1662315-ce34645.twc1.net/wp-content/uploads/cities.json');

// Decode the JSON data

if (is_array($json_data) && !is_wp_error($json_data)) {

    $cities = json_decode($json_data['body']);

} else {

    echo 'Error fetching JSON data';

}

// Get the city names

$city_names = [];

if (!empty($cities->cities)) {

    foreach ($cities->cities as $city) {

        $city_names[] = $city->name;

    }

}

add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form', 'add_custom_dropdown_after_shipping_form');

function add_custom_dropdown_after_shipping_form() {

    // Check if it's the checkout page

    if (is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) {

        // Create a dropdown of cities

        echo '<select id="city-dropdown">';

        echo '<option value="">Select a city</option>';

        foreach ($city_names as $city_name) {

            echo '<option value="' . $city_name . '">' . $city_name . '</option>';

        }

        echo '</select>';

    }

}
```

I have used many methods to get data like `get_content_files` but not working, the main issue is unable to fetch data from JSON. Is there any specific way to place JSON file in WordPress or anything else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to fetch the JSON data from an external URL. The wp_remote_get() function is used to fetch data from an external URL, but in your case, the JSON file is located in your WordPress directory.

To fetch the JSON data from your WordPress directory, you can use the get_file_contents() function. The get_file_contents() function takes the path to the file as its argument and returns the contents of the file as a string.

The following code will fetch the JSON data from your WordPress directory and decode it:

$json_data = get_file_contents('wp-content/uploads/file.json');

// Decode the JSON data

$cities = json_decode($json_data);

Once you have decoded the JSON data, you can get the city names as follows:

// Get the city names

$city_names = [];

if (!empty($cities->cities)) {

```
foreach ($cities->cities as $city) {

    $city_names[] = $city->name;

}
```

}

The rest of your code is correct, so you should be able to use it to create the dropdown of cities.

Here is the complete code:

cities)) {

    foreach ($cities->cities as $city) {

        $city_names[] = $city->name;

    }

}

add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form', 'add_custom_dropdown_after_shipping_form');

function add_custom_dropdown_after_shipping_form() {

    // Check if it's the checkout page

    if (is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) {

        // Create a dropdown of cities

        echo '';

        echo 'Select a city';

        foreach ($city_names as $city_name) {

            echo '' . $city_name . '';

        }

        echo '';

    }

}

?>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy